# .NET Core 6: Use my DbContext in Authorization Handler

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an authorization handler that needs to pull data from the database to complete the authorization logic. The idea is that users are only allowed to certain areas after posting a given number of blog posts.

Code as follows:

```
namespace MyProject.Authorisation
{
    public class MinimumPostRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public MinimumPostRequirement (int postCount)
        {
            PostCount = postCount;
        }

        public int PostCount { get; }
    }

    public class MinimumPostRequirement Handler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumPostRequirement >
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authContext, ApprovedUserRequirement requirement)
        {
            
            using (MyDbContext _context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                int? postCount = _context.Posts.Where(post => post.UserName == authContext.User.Identity.Name).Count();

                if(postCount == null)
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

                if(postCount >= requirement.PostCount)
                {
                    authContext.Succeed(requirement);
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I declare it in Program.cs:

```
//DB Connection
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(MyConnection));


//authorisation
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireMinimumPosts", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumPostRequirement(3)));
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumPostRequirementHandler>();
```

I know there is a dependency injection issue when adding a singleton, so I have also tried using in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumPostRequirementHandler>();
```

And

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumPostRequirementHandler>();
```

All result in the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

The database works for all other site operations. The problem only arises when I add `[Authorize(Policy = "RequireMinimumPosts")]` to the methods I want to restrict.

How would you write this code so that it works? How does dependency injection work in this context? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: The Error stems from the way you initialze "MyDbContext" in your "MinimumPostRequirementHandler" class. You configured DbContext for Dependency Injection, but in this case you are newing up you own instance.
Try to pass "MyDbContext" through constructor injection in your "MinimunPostrequirementHandler" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the `DbContext` into the constructor of your `MinimumPostRequirementHandler` so it will be resolved by the DI container.

```
public class MinimumPostRequirementHandler
    : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumPostRequirement>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public MinimumPostRequirementHandler( MyDbContext dbContext )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authContext, ApprovedUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        // use _dbContext here
    }
}
```

Register the handler as scoped.

Comment: Bam! Simple solution that works!